# Unable to insert to database Android

Tags: android

I have this code below that is suppose to get the result of the barcode being scanned and adding it into the database. The problem is that after i scanned the code and try to add it into my database it keeps giving the toastMessage "Something is wrong".

Sorry i'm current a newbie in android studio and am not really sure what's the problem with my current codes. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```
public void AddData(String newEntry) {
            boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(newEntry);

            if (insertData) {
                toastMessage("Data Successfully Inserted!");
            } else {
                toastMessage("Something went wrong");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void handleResult(Result result) {
            final String newEntry = result.getText();
            Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
            Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);
                }
            });
            builder.setMessage(result.getText());
            AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
            alert1.show();
            AddData(newEntry);

        }

        private void toastMessage(String message){
            Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for my databaseHelper.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "list_table";
    private static final String COL1 = "ID";
    private static final String COL2 = "code";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL2 +" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, item);

        Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

}
```

Comment: you can try this lib,very easy to use for SQLite,https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/

Comment: Your code seems ok. Just uninstall the app from the emulator/device and then try again.

Comment: @forpas wow that seriously worked thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try catch exceptions in the insert.

```
try {
   id = db.insertOrThrow(table, cv...);
} catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e(TAG, e.message());
}
```

Comment: put this inside my boolean addData?

Comment: yes, if row is not inserted, an exception is thrown, capturing the exception allows you to know why insertion failed.